# How to rewrite switch/case code with junit 4 to junit 5 or testng

Tags: java, testing, junit

I have the code:

```
Result result = null;
    for(int i = 1; i <= setOfConfiguration; i++){

        switch(typeOfAgreement){
                case "GUS":
                    result = JUnitCore.runClasses(first.class); break;
                case "MUS":
                    result = JUnitCore.runClasses(second.class); break;
                case "DUS":
                    result = JUnitCore.runClasses(third.class); break;
        }
      }
```

How to rewrite switch/case code with junit 4 to junit 5 or testng

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39111501/whats-the-equivalent-of-org-junit-runner-junitcore-runclasses-in-junit-5

Comment: I feel this is actually a duplicate of the question that Evgeny linked to; and I'd like to vote to close it as such.  Unfortunately, I have only a duplicate-hammer, rather than a vote.  So if a few other people duplicate-vote this, I will hammer it.

Comment: ok, but how can I add condition in junit-platform-launcher to run specific class?

Comment: Reading is fundamental

Comment: But how can _switch/case_ relate to `selenium`? Am I missing something? @BillHileman

Comment: I shouldn't have made the snarky comment, apologies.  It was meant for the OP who seemed to be responding without acknowledging either of the two previous comments.

Comment: I have never used junit-platform-launcher, so all I could do to help you is to look up the documentation and copy it in here.  You should be able to follow the example in the JUnit5 User Guide, which is linked to in the answer to the other question.  But I don't have any more information than you do, about how to use it, sorry.